# iOS Simulator is not displaying objects

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm completely new to iOS and Swift development and trying to write hello world program by following this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-hello-world-app-swift/).

When I ran my code I cannot see components. Seems like they are located on top of the simulator but I can't see.

Xcode version 6.2
target iOS 7.0 and later.

I execute simulator iPhone 6. This is what I can see:

[image]

Can someone point me where should I change to get this interface fit to phone size? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: The interface is too big for your computer screen, so it is showing a scrolling version of the interface.  Choose **Window->Scale->50%** to see the whole phone interface.

Comment: Please PLEASE learn to call it iOS, not ISO. This will help us to help you. Also, look up (Google it) "iOS layout", maybe including things like "AutoLayout" or "frames bounds". Right now your topmost button is looking like it's situated on the Y-axis at point 0 or less.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I do n't have such option here. I'm using MacBook Air. There isn't anything like scale inside the window.

Comment: @dfd Thanks for point out my mistake. I will try your solution.

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Where are you looking for it Xcode or Simulator?

Comment: @LeoDabus I checked both xcode and simulator. I do n't see any option to change the scale. This simulator window does not have a scroll bar either.

Comment: @dfd I check my top button Y-axis is not 0 it is 77.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- Open the storyboard.
- Select the View Controller
- Select the fourth icon in the right side.
- In simulated Metrics we have an option for size. Change it to iPhone
  4 inch or as per your requirement.

For more reference see the screen shot:

[image]